# Estoy tratando de hacer un grafico interactivo utilizando un checkboxgroupinput

Tags: r, ggplot2

Los comandos que utilice son los siguientes:

```
checkboxGroupInput("Jax","Meses", choices = unique(Base$month), selected = unique(Base$month))

renderPlot(
Base  %>% 
     filter(month%in%input$jax) %>% 
     group_by(month) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=month, y=deaths)) + geom_col())
```

Al ejecutar el dashboard el grafico aparece sin informacion.

[image: grafico]

Comment: Me parece que estas cambiando el nombre del input. En el ui al definir el checkBox lo escribes con mayúscula "Jax" mientras que en el server al hacer el filtro con minúscula "jax". También puedes revisar la consola de R al cerrar la app en busca de algún error.

Comment: Hola complementando a lo que menciona Rolando el in lo tienes que separar  filter(month%in%input$jax) ,  filter(month %in% input$jax) saludos